# How to re-measure TextView width?

Tags: android, performance, textview

I am generating a listview, that contains a custom representation of my objects. I use a well-known holder pattern. One part of this custom view, I want to generate, is the list of tags. The number of tags is different, for this reason I do dynamic inflating of TextViews at certain ([custom layout](https://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/)). I thought, it would be a good practise to reuse these textviews via HolderPattern. In order to do this, before populating some new TextViews, I check, if there are any present, and simply replace the text. But when I do so, the size of these previous TextViews remains fitting previous text, not the new one. Question is, does it make sence to recalculate the width of these reused textviews compared to reinflating the new one?

Comment: I think you can just call textview.postInvalidate();

Comment: @Arlind that didn't work for me. Do you know, where does the measurement occur and what events do inflict it?